# Add / Edit Field to Convert Lead Menu

Tags: record-type, custom, default-value, convert

When a user converts a lead by default it would add a new account, with account name.
Not sure who/how it was setup that a Record Type field is here.
Where might it be possible to see this behaviour?
Secondly, this field defaults to affiliate. Would this be setup in a flow or it just picks them option alphabetically as the first one? Then a user changes this.
Hope this is clear

[image: Convert Lead]

Answer (score 0):

The user has more than 1 available Account record type. See this document for more information - [How is account record type chosen when converting leads?](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389598&type=1)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.